# Decompose a video frame into an array of RGB values - C++

Tags: c++, multi-threading

I am currently trying to write a motion detection algorithm for a college project (Parallel programming). My idea is to decompose a video into multiple frames, which will then be converted into a 2D-array of significant values ( here the average of the Red, Blue, Green values ). The N-th array can then be compared to the (N-1)-th array and detect the change. I would like to implement my algorithm with either OpenMp or MPI. Since I've already searched for some librairies that could help me achieve this decomposition task but didn't find something adequate. My question is: Do you know any librairies or other methods that could help me achieve this task ?